# Unity multiplayer(android and ios) using socket.io

Tags: unity-game-engine, socket.io

I am trying to achieve multiplayer game for android and IOS, I have multiple options,

1. Photon
2. Mirror
3. MLAPI
4. Socket.io

option 1,2,3 are not working for me as I found out that I cannot program a dedicated server for my specific needs and access db from them.
I am left with socket.io but I am not sure if it supports android and IOS games, plugins I found are mostly for webGL and standalone. Does anyone know if socket.io works for android and ios games made with unity smoothly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. it's working well on android and iOS games.
But it has some problems to make games.
If your game is not big game like 2D, Card Game it's ok for you to develop with socket.io but if it's big game like 3D style(FPS, RPG, RTS...), you should use good multiplayer services like Photon Server.
For database it's not problem for you to do use database.
Of course you have to make backend to use database.
But think about to split multiplayer server and backend server using database.
Then it's same with Photon, Mirror, MLAPI, Socket.IO.
Only you can use Socket.IO on backend server so it's only comfortable for you.
So you can select multiplayer server with your game style.
I hope it will help your project.